# issues with the `DocIssuance_IssueTicket` SOAP API

Tags: ttl, amadeus, ticket-system

We are currently using the Enterprise APIs AMADEUS.com and have encountered some issues with the `DocIssuance_IssueTicket` SOAP API. When using this API, we receive an error with the following `errorGroup` in the SOAP body. Please note that I have converted the XML response to JSON for clarity:

```
        "errorGroup": 
    {
        "errorOrWarningCodeDetails": {
           "errorDetails": {
                "errorCode": "24463"
            }
        },
        "errorWarningDescription": {
            "freeTextDetails": {
                "textSubjectQualifier": "3",
                "source": "M",
                "encoding": "1"
            },
            "freeText": "VALIDATING CARRIERS DO NOT MATCH :REPRICE OR MODIFY FV"
        }
    }
```

We use the following flow to issue the ticket:

1. Air_SellFromRecommendation
2. PNR_AddMultiElements
3. Fare_PricePNRWithBookingClass
4. Ticket_CreateTSTFromPricing
5. PNR_AddMultiElements (again)
6. DocIssuance_IssueTicket

We do not encounter any errors from steps 1 to 5, and we execute these APIs with no delay. We have also tested step 6 with a 1-minute delay, but the result is the same.

Could you please advise which SOAP API we should use for this purpose?

Additionally, we do not have access to the `PNR Request Time Limit` SOAP API.

Thank you.

we want to get a ticket number after issue ticket.

Comment: For support to Enterprise related questions you can get in touch directly with your account manager.

Comment: Hi Naeim, you can use Command_Cryptic and findout if you get the same error message. You can try 
TTP/TKT/T1
Looks like some mismatch between the TST validating carrier en the one you specified in the docIssuance RQ.
Can you tell me more so that we can guide you?
Have you posted the same question on servicehub?